# Use different reuseIdentifier for selected cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, reusability

I had a UITableView uses reuseIdentifier `cellIdentifier`, when one UITableViewCell is selected, I need to change its reuseIdentifier to `selectedIdentifier` and add some `UIView` into cell's contentView. So that the selected one won't be mixed with the normal cells when tableview scrolling.

Or just don't reuse the UITableViewCell when it's selected. Anyway what I want is keep what the selected cell was and reuse the rest of cells when scrolling.

Could anyone tell how to implement that. Thanks very much.

Comment: Why? What are you actually trying to achieve? You question would indicate you aren't using cell selection / your model properly...

Comment: Why not add a bool in your data source array to keep track of your selected states?